# Are these two definitions for dual norm equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces

Suppose there is a $p$-norm $\left\|\cdot\right\|_p$, the dual function at $z$ of it is,
$$\sup\left\{ z^{T} x-\left\|x\right\|_p:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\right\}$$

The second is,

$$
 \sup\left\{ z^{T} x : x \in \mathbb{R}^n, \left\|x\right\|_p \le 1\right\}
$$ (e.g. [Proving that the dual of the $\mathcal{l}_p$ norm is the $\mathcal{l}_q$ norm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265721/proving-that-the-dual-of-the-mathcall-p-norm-is-the-mathcall-q-norm/265757#265757))

Answer (score 0):

Using basic knowledge from convex analysis, the answer is "no". The first expression is the value of the *conjugate function* of $\|\cdot\|_p$ at $z$, the second one is the value of the *support function* of the closed unit ball of the norm $\|\cdot\|_p$ at $z$. See, e.g. R. T. Rockafellar, *Convex Analysis*. The conjugate function is the indicator function of the closed unit ball of norm $\|\cdot\|_q$, where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, that is, it equals $0$ on the closed unit ball of $\|\cdot\|_q$, and it equals $+\infty$ otherwise. The support function coincides with $\|\cdot\|_q$.

Comment: Another point of view at - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2418077.