# Minimize $ {L}_{p} $ Norm Regularized with a Linear Term (Conjugate Function of the Norm Function)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization

The problem is given as following:

$$ \min_{x} {a}^{T} x + \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{p} $$

Namely minimizing a ${L}_{p} $ norm term regularized by a linear term.

The above form occurs repeatedly on the dual forms of convex optimization problems as it is related to the Conjugate Function.

I will add my solution as Wiki Solution.
Please add your own or validate the community solution.
I will mark as an answer other people solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Problem

$$ \min_{x} {a}^{T} x + \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{p} $$

### The Solution

First pay attention that by setting $ y = -x $ the problem can be transformed into:

$$ \min_{y} -{a}^{T} y + \lambda \left\| y \right\|_{p} $$

Defining $ q $ such that $ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1 $.
One could show that $ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{p} $ is the dual of $ \left\| \cdot \right\|_{q} $.

#### Case I - $ \left\| a \right\|_{q} \leq \lambda $

By [Holder Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) $ {a}^{T} y \leq \left| {a}^{T} y \right| \leq \left\| a \right\|_{q} \left\| y \right\|_{p} $ hence:

$$
\begin{align*}
-{a}^{T} y + \lambda \left\| y \right\|_{p} & \geq - \left\| a \right\|_{q} \left\| y \right\|_{p} + \lambda \left\| y \right\|_{p} \\
& = \left\| y \right\|_{p} \left( \lambda - \left\| a \right\|_{q} \right)
\end{align*}
$$

This is a non negative term which is minimized by $ y = \boldsymbol{0} \Rightarrow x = \boldsymbol{0} $ which means the minimum value is given by $ 0 $.

#### Case II - $ \left\| a \right\|_{q} > \lambda $

By definition as the dual norm $ \left\| a \right\|_{q} > \lambda \Rightarrow \exists u, \, \left\| u \right\|_{p} \leq 1 : {u}^{T} a > \lambda $.
Choosing $ y = t u $ yields:

$$
\begin{align*}
-t {a}^{T} u + \lambda t \left\| u \right\|_{p} & = t \left( \lambda \left\| u \right\|_{p} - {a}^{T} u \right) & \text{} \\ 
& = t \left( \lambda - {a}^{T} u \right) \xrightarrow[]{t \to \infty} - \infty & \text{Since $ \left\| u \right\|_{p} \leq 1 $ and $ {a}^{T} u > \lambda $ }
\end{align*}
$$

#### Summary

$$ \min_{x} {a}^{T} x + \lambda \left\| x \right\|_{p} = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } \left\| a \right\|_{q} \leq \lambda \\ 
-\infty & \text{ if } \left\| a \right\|_{q} > \lambda 
\end{cases} $$

The above could be generalized to any Norm and its Dual Norm.
Basically proving the Conjugate Function of a Norm is the Indicator Function of its Dual Norm.

### Please Validate This Solution (Wiki Solution)

Comment: I think you are essentially proving that the conjugate of a norm is the indicator function of the dual norm unit ball.  You could replace the $p$-norm with a general norm $\| \cdot \|$, and replace the $q$-norm with just the dual norm $\| \cdot \|_*$. We still have the inequality $a^T y \leq \| a \| \|y\|_*$, so your argument still works.  (Except, I think in case II you have only shown that the infimum of the lower bound is $-\infty$, and it is not yet clear that the infimum of $-a^T y + \lambda \|y\|_p$ is $-\infty$.)

Comment: In case II, if $\| a \|_* = \sup_{\|u\| \leq 1} \, \langle a, u \rangle > \lambda$, this means that there exists a vector $u$ with $\| u \| = 1$ such that $\langle a, u \rangle > \lambda$. So, $-\langle a, u \rangle + \lambda \| u \| < 0$. Now by taking $y$ to be a positive scalar multiple of $u$, we can make $-\langle a, y \rangle +  \lambda \|y \|$ as negative as we like.  A proof like this is given on slide 10 of Vandenberghe's 236c notes about the conjugate function. http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/236C/lectures/conj.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I'll take $\lambda = 1$ for simplicity. Let $f(x) = \| x \|_p$. Note that
\begin{equation}
\inf_x \, a^T x + \|x \|_p = - \sup_x \, \langle - a, x \rangle - \| x \|_p = - f^*(-a).
\end{equation}
The conjugate of a norm is the indicator function for the dual norm unit ball.
Moreover, the dual norm for the $p$-norm is the $q$-norm, where $q = 1 - 1/p$. Thus,
$$
f^*(-a) = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{if } \| a \|_q \leq 1, \\
\infty & \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
It follows that
$$
\inf_x \, a^T x + \|x \|_p  = \begin{cases} 0 & \quad \text{if } \| a \|_q \leq 1, \\
-\infty & \quad \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Nice one! I +1 it. What about my community solution, do you find any issue?